# pyreverse uml diagram with customized color

Tags: python, uml, pyreverse

I'm trying to generate a UML diagram with `pyreverse` but I want all the nodes of the diagram to be coloured blue. There is currently an option called `--colorized` ([see here](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/pull/4850)) that puts different colours to different nodes, but I don't know how to make these diagrams blue with a command.

Right now, I am running

```sh
pyreverse -o png -p xxx xxx --colorized --max-color-depth 1
```

and this generates a uml with a faint blue color, but I want a darker blue.

Does some one know how to do this or has any idea what to do?

Thanks!

**Update:** I found a way around by making an svg file and then editing it with

```py
with open("path.svg", "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    filedata = file.read()
filedata = filedata.replace("aliceblue", "#bde0ff")
with open("path.svg", "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    file.write(filedata)
```

Answer (score 3):

There is currently (as of V2.13.9) no way to define a custom colour palette.
I added a [feature request](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/6738) on GitHub for this.